# Mutual TLS with embedded Tomcat and Common Name (CN)

Tags: tomcat, reverse-proxy, mutual-authentication, embedded-tomcat

We run a REST service using embedded Tomcat.  Our app requires Mutual TLS to authenticate and authorizes by extracts the CN from the client certificate and verifies the permissions in a set of authorized users.

This works fine with a reverse proxy, like Nginx using a config which extracts the CN and passes it in the HTTP header:

```
proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-CN $ssl_client_s_dn_cn;
```

Instead, is it possible in embedded Tomcat to extract the CN instead of using a reverse proxy?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We've not found way to do this in Tomcat w/out a reverse proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..and as a Tomcat committer I'd say, RTFM.
The [`SSLValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/SSLValve.html) will read the Base 64 PEM public cert of your client, inject the `X509Certificate` and then your [`Realm`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/realm.html#Special_Features) can provide a `X509UsernameRetriever` to read out what you need.